# JQuery UI Resizable Containment Bounding Box

Tags: jquery-ui-resizable

I am hoping there is a way to set a containment bounding box in pixels rather than an html element.  I found a post with a Draggable example of the same thing, their example looked like this:

```
$( "#img" ).draggable({ containment: [x1, y1, x2, y2] });
```

I tried the same thing with resizable which resulted in an error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined"
```

Is there a similar syntax that would work with resizable? The only things I've been able to find were containment: HTML_ELEMENT, and also maxWidth, maxHeight, minWidth, minHeight.

My goal is to contain within the resizing element within a certain amount of pixels from the edge of the containing element.

Thank you everyone for your time

Comment: What is the value of x1 in relation to?

Comment: @ksav element one's (the element being dragged) left position: `ui.draggable.position().left`

Comment: @Souleste and y1 is in relation to the element's top position?  They really needed some explanation of that.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I think the general answer here is also "to the window".  Seems like these are coordinates on the general window, and not relative to a parent element or anything.

Comment: @daprezjer This [codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/NWryqPM) may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `maxWidth, minWidth, maxheight, minHeight` options on the resizable element in the `start` resizable function, or you can set min and maxes on the element with css.

```js
$('.widget1').resizable();

var minW = 50;
var maxW = 200;
var minH = 50;
var maxH = 200;

$('.widget2').resizable({
  start: function(e, ui) {
    var minWidth = $(this).resizable("option", "minWidth", minW);
    var maxWidth = $(this).resizable("option", "maxWidth", maxW);
    var minHeight = $(this).resizable("option", "minHeight", minH);
    var maxHeight = $(this).resizable("option", "maxHeight", maxH);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.widget {
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.widget1 {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="widget1 widget"></div>

<div class="widget2 widget"></div>
```